# Можно ли по данным таблицы в HTML-файле  построить график?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте!
У меня задача такая - нужно считываемые данные датчика самолета ( ну это условно, что датчика, просто рандом) записывать в файл, где возможно визуальное представление с помощью цвета. Т.е. пишу в таблицу, а ячейки закрашиваю соответствующим ситуации цветом - норма, преавария, авария. И теперь нужно эту таблицу превратить в график. По одной оси параметр, под другой время, которое тоже пишется в таблицу
Можно ли по данным таблицы в HTML-файле  построить график?
Знак * в таблице = параметр, равен предыдущему.

```
<table border="3" class="he" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" width="60%">
<tr align =center>
<td> Время </td>
<td> Высота, м </td>
<td> Скорость, км/ч</td>
<td> Температура за бортом </td>
</tr>  
<tr align =center><td>0:43:3</td><td>10</td><td class = norma>110</td><td>23</td>        </tr> 
<tr align =center><td>0:43:4</td> <td>100</td> <td class = norma>120</td> <td>15</td> </tr> 
<tr align =center><td>0:43:6</td> <td>200</td> <td class = norma>75</td> <td>10</td> </tr> 
<tr align =center><td>0:43:7</td> <td>*</td> <td class = predavar>65</td> <td>*</td> </tr> 
<tr align =center><td>0:43:8</td> <td>300</td> <td class = avar>40</td> <td>3</td> 
</tr></table>
```

Подскажите, можно ли какими-нибудь средствами построить график по такой таблице или надо экспортировать данные в EXcel?

Comment: Абсолютно непонятно, зачем брать в качестве источника данных HTML, если эти самые данные и так есть в сыром виде. Но если так хочется левой ногой через правое ухо - распарсить HTML можно кучей способов, от регекспов до DOM, всё зависит от ваших инструментов (ЯП?)

Comment: возможно html формирует не автор

Comment: Во-первых, внимательно почитайте условие. Во-вторых, у этого вопроса есть предыстория :)

Comment: откуда же данные есть в сыром виде?
основная программа на С#, каждую секунду по таймеру приходят новые данные, и пишутся в файл, в таблицу..
данные,которые приходят - это заранее приготовленные массивы, но время-то всегда будет писаться разное..

Comment: >каждую секунду по таймеру приходят новые данные, и пишутся в файл, в таблицу.. данные,которые приходят - это заранее приготовленные массивы

То есть проблема в том, что график нужно строить по данным, которые копятся в течении какого-то времени? Опять же не вижу особых проблем, просто наряду с HTML и некой "таблицей" нужно сохранять их в каком-то удобном виде. Например, в виде CSV, или в БД. Ну а если уж совсем никак - да, парсить HTML. Но тогда вопрос тот же: какими технологиями располагаем? Во всяком случае и регекспы,и DOM доступны везде.

Comment: я не знаю регекспы и DOM..(
про СSV  сейчас прочитала, а как можно из такого файла построить график по данным и куда этот график рисовать?

Comment: Это уж вам видней, как строить график по вашим же данным, и куда и как его рисовать.

Comment: честно, я не знаю как это сделать..
если вы пишете, что не видите особых проблем, подскажите как можно по примерным данным нарисовать  график


   0:43:3  80   
   0:43:4  100  
   0:43:6  200
   0:43:7  210

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов на `PHP`

```
$page = file_get_contents('путь к файлу html');
```

подробно о методе [здесь](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Потом с переменой `$page`, в которой находиться станица производить нужные манипуляции при помощи регулярных выражении, метод [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Это лишь как маленький пример, для частного случая.
Задавайте более точные вопросы для более емких ответов

Comment: а можно маленький пример использования метода preg_match?

Comment: Поскольку комменты закончились - тут.

>как можно по примерным данным нарисовать график

Очень просто: нужно поставить 4 точки в верхнем правом квадранте координатной сетки, координаты по оси Y у них будут 80, 100, 200 и 210, а по оси X - как выберете временную шкалу.

P.S. А вы что, всерьёз это спрашиваете???

Comment: как это сделать программно я не знаю

Comment: может как-то экспортировать данные из таблицы в excel, там построить график, но можно ли вернуть его как картинку, чтобы обратно на   html-страничку вставить?

ни одно действие как сделать это программно я не знаю( 
(начиная от экспорта данных в excel )